# An equivalent to hash-hash in the name of a define

Tags: c, metaprogramming, c-preprocessor, c99

In a `#define` one can use `A ## B` to concatenate preprocessor variables and defines to an identifier.

```
#define ADD_UNDERSCORE(X) X##_
/* ADD_UNDERSCORE(n) -> n_ */
```

Is there an equivalent leftside of the #define? E.g.

```
#define A a
#define B b
#define A##B(X) X
/* ab(n) -> n */
```

Comment: In the comment in your second example, do you mean `ab(n) -> n`? I can't quite work out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Vicky: yes, I meant `ab(n)`, corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In a macro definition, the first token after the `define` has to be an identifier ([(draft) ISO/IEC 9899;1999](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), 6.10, page 149).

There is no other preprocessing of the `#define` directives which could make an identifier out of something else. In particular, the standard specifies (6.10.3):

> The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not subject to macro
>   expansion unless otherwise stated.

And it isn't stated "otherwise" for the macro name.

Comment: Too bad. :-( Thank you for the precise answer!